# storing a tuple in sql or gql database?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, tuples

this might be a really simple question, but im struggling with it.

could you help me find a way to store two pieces of form data in the GAE datastore, as a tuple?

thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store it as two separate properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them as two separate properties, or, if they are of the same datatype, you can put them in a [ListProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListProperty).